# Working out coordinates for a bounding box with 3 mile radius from original lat/long

Tags: geometry

I have a latitude/longitude. I need to get lat/long coordinates that create a bounding box covering roughly a 3 mile radius around the original location. Ideally I'd like to have 4 sets of lat long creating the bounding box - with the center being the original location.

I know how to measure the distance between two different longitude/latitudes but in this instance I obviously only have the initial point to work from.

Comment: Do you mean this is on a sphere? And do you want to draw a circle or a square on the sphere?

Comment: Basically I need to get 4 sets of lat/long that draw a box with the original location in the center of the box. The lat/long would equate to each corner of the box. I've just been reading about flat earth approximation which would be good enough for me as it's only 3 miles?

Comment: I think a flat approximation would be good enough for $3$ miles.

Comment: The problem I'm having is finding info on how to do this. loads of info online about how to calculate distance between two locations you already have the lat/long for but nothing for what I need to do! On top of this my geometry isn't exactly strong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose your original point is $(\theta,\phi)$ in radians.

Let $s$ be arc length, in your case, $s=3$, $r$ be the radius of sphere. If you are talking about earth, then $r$ is the radius of earth in miles.

The new latitude will be $\theta\pm \frac{s}{r}$. The new longitude will be $\phi \pm \frac{s}{r}$.

$\pm$ means $+$ or $-$. So the new points are: $(\theta+\frac{s}{r}, \phi +\frac{s}{r}), (\theta+\frac{s}{r}, \phi -\frac{s}{r}), (\theta-\frac{s}{r}, \phi +\frac{s}{r}), (\theta-\frac{s}{r}, \phi -\frac{s}{r})$, in the order of upper right, lower right, upper left, lower left.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Please forgive my lack of math here..so this gives me one new lat/long pair right? If I understand I first need to convert the lat/long to radians (Radians = Degrees * PI / 180), then plus 3 divided by 3963 (radius of earth in miles) - not sure how to use the plus-minus here though?

Comment: Yes, the conversion is correct. I edited the points in the answer.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for your help on this!

Comment: Yes, I think so, if you need them in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

The box from the accepted answer is not big enough in terms of the longitude range to cover the region within distance `s` of the original point. If the original point is not on the equator, the two meridian lines that are the tangent lines of a circle centred at the original points should touch the circle at a place slightly closer to the (nearest) pole than the original point. Therefore, the tangent point should be at a higher latitude than the original point. Assume you have the original point $P_0 (Lat_p, Lon_p)$
The upper and lower latitude bound is $Lat_p \pm \frac{s}{r_\text{earth}}$, which is the same as the accepted answer. While the left and right bound is $Lon_p \pm arcsin(\frac{sin(\frac{s}{r_\text{earth}})}{cos(Lat_p)})$. Special treatment might be necessary when the box covers the pole or the antimeridian, a detailed explanation can be found at http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates#RefBronstein.

Though it is a very old question, it is still valid for many with a similar problem to solve. To avoid more people getting misled, the accepted answer gets more inaccurate when the original point is closer to the poles or, in a more general context, when $s$ becomes larger. The detailed explanation can be found at https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/19221/89860 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/238260/14018440. The mistake that my intuition matched the accepted answer here led to a disaster in my project. I just want people who are searching for an answer to a similar question to think again when seeing it. I could not comment on that answer so wrote it here. Please reviewers do not delete my answer again.